# How can I pass my query values from mysqli_fetch_array?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert values into a table in my database. The first param is a non null variable, the next two are the two columns I want to pass in as well. What is wrong with my logic here.

```
$query  = "SELECT cnum, cname FROM course WHERE specialization = '0'";  
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

 if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

 $rows = $result->num_rows;    
for ($j =0; $j<$rows;++$j) {

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $query = "INSERT INTO student_schedule VALUES ('$studentID', '$row[0]', '$row[1]', '0')";

     $result = $conn->query($query);
     if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

 }
```

Comment: Is that not working? Any error thrown?

Comment: Yeah I get the expected $result to be parameter but boolean instead passed to mysqli_fetch_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your solution

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT cnum, cname FROM course WHERE specialization = '0'";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO student_schedule VALUES ('" . $conn->real_escape_string($studentID) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($row[0]) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($row[1]) . "', '0')");
    $insert = $conn->query($insertQuery);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);
}
?>
```

Also, as a general rule, I suggest you don't mix MySQLi Procedural code with Object-Oriented code. Lastly, I also suggest you remove error outputting `$conn->error`, instead, capture the error and print out a custom error message instead. This reduces injection attacks.

Comment: after changing to your solution I get Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\journalism.php on line 140

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\journalism.php on line 140

Notice: Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' in C:\xampp\htdocs\journalism.php on line 142

Comment: @Murph_Fish change `$insert = $conn->query($insertQuery);` to `$result = $conn->query($insertQuery);` incase you are using the solution by @LFlare. also $ missing in your if (!result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

Comment: @VipindasKS after those fixes I am getting undefined offset 0 and undefined offset 1 pointing to $insertquery  any ideas?

Comment: Did you change `if (!result)` to `if (!$result)`? I mean did you add dollar sign to the result variable?

Comment: @Murph_Fish can you please post the error? And, which line causing error.

Comment: @VipindasKS Yes I fixed that before I got the error mentioned above so it has to be something else. The array in the while should hold two values so those indexes should be correct

Comment: @Murph_Fish change `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)`  where are your field names in your query?

Comment: @VipindasKS That was it! Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, was too sleepy when I posted my solution, made such a bad mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), that might to be the reason why it doesn't work properly.

You should escape the data before including it into an SQL query:

```
for ($j =0; $j<$rows;++$j) {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO student_schedule VALUES (?, ?, ?, '0')";
    $query->bind_param('iss', $studentID, $row[0], $row[1]);
    $result = $query->execute();
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

}
```

You can find more information on the `bind_param()` function in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: after plugging this in I get Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 5 by reference in C:\......... on line 145

Comment: @Murph_Fish yes, there was an issue. The answer is edited now, you can try again.